# Is there a Russian translation of the website and wiki?

Tags: ros, translation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that many developers from Russia used the ROS, but unfortunately there is no material translated into *Russian*. Is it interesting for Community to have a translation of the site and other materials into local languages? I still found the translation in *French*, *German*, *Japanese* and so on. *Russian*, *Ukrainian* and *Belorussian* do not see, but it's a huge audience of developers.

With Best regards,
Wagan Sarukhanov

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208754/is-there-a-russian-translation-of-the-website-and-wiki?/) by [Wagan Sarukhanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/22367/wagan-sarukhanov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wagan Sarukhanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/22367/wagan-sarukhanov/) on 2015-05-07**:
I'll try to translate couple of pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Translation in progress, colleagues are welcome ))

---

Originally posted by [Wagan Sarukhanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/22367/wagan-sarukhanov/) with karma: 33 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0